# Having trouble appending a multi-line array in a `for` loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, input, append

Not sure how to word my question. I'm trying to collect data with `input` in a `for` loop and append it every time. I want it to look like this: Each loop of `input`, I want to enter:  `SOL $XXX $ZZZ`, `BTC $XXX $ZZZ`, `ETH $XXX $ZZZ`, etc.

And I want the finished output to look like this:

```markdown
* `BTC 4/12@07:59pm :: $291.42 @ $40,173.45`
* `SOL 4/12@07:59pm :: $267.02 @ $103.28`
* `LTC 4/12@07:59pm :: $220.91 @ $104.82`
* `ETH 4/12@07:59pm :: $177.43 @ $3,031.23`
* `wETH 4/12@07:59pm :: $45.20 @ $3,031.23`
* `Total 4/12@07:59pm :: $1,001.98`
```

I'll be able to format it, I just can't figure out how to keep appending the input. I'm sure it'll be something simple that I just can't picture at the moment. Hopefully I worded this well enough for someone to understand my query.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you talking about string? why don't you concatenate strings in your for loop?

Comment: No. I want every string I supply with `input` to keep appending the final output. 
Basically like this: `var=input; var+=var` or `var.append(var)` and have the final output look like it does in the OP. But I'm having difficulty with picturing how it should go.

Answer (score 1):

So we have 2 issues here. 1 making the for loop, 2 printing stuff out.

For 1 we'll just do a while loop (since we don't know when you'll stop) based on the input:

```
from datetime import datetime
user_input = "not empty"
inputs_list = []
while True:
  user_input = input("What are your coordinates?")
  if user_input == "":
    break
  split_string = user_input.split(" ", 1)
  string_with_date = datetime.now().strftime(
    "{prefix} %m/%d@%I:%M%p {coordinates}".format(prefix=split_string[0], coordinates=split_string[1])
  )
  inputs_list.append(string_with_date)
```

This will keep looping until you give an empty return to the input call. Then we can print all of your results with:

```
for row in inputs_list:
  print("* `{row}`".format(row=row))
```

The heavy lifting is done by this part:

```
string_with_date = datetime.now().strftime(
    "{prefix} %m/%d@%I:%M%p {coordinates}".format(prefix=split_string[0], coordinates=split_string[1])
  )
```

We use the split method to cut your inputs at the first space and glue them back together in the strftime argument with the date in between.

For more info on [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) or on [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), check the documentation linked in this message.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for, I'm just having trouble with the formatting on it. Doing `{row[0]} {row[1]}` etc isn't working. Tried adding `split` to `input` but that's not working. Thank you very much.

Comment: I got formatting to work on the `string_with_date` bit but now it's printing it one line at a time as I enter the input. Printing it in the for loop at the bottom is giving me trouble with formatting.

Comment: What is the issue with the formatting? Did you want it to print one at a time or all at the end?

Comment: Nothing wrong with formatting anymore. Only problem is it's only one or the other. Using `print` in your `for` loop that works but doesn't format it properly. Or I can use the `string_with_date` you wrote but it doesn't print it all at once. It prints every time I give input.

Comment: I combined both in the first snippet. Look at the last few lines. I append all the string_with_date results to a list and then I print everything in the list.

Comment: The `for` loop isn't combined in the first snippet. I added it to the bottom of the first snippet and it works but I can't split the lines, i.e `SOL 4/13@12:01am :`. Your `string_with_date` isn't getting used in the first snippet at all.

Comment: I just fixed the mistake in the first snippet. I was appending `user_input` instead of `string_with_date`. It is now fixed.